# URL Rewriting on a S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, rewrite

Is there anyway at all to setup URL rewriting for a static-hosted website on S3? I'm in the process of migrating over an existing website and some of the URLs I would like for them to have a 301 redirect and I would like not to have DOT html for all my website files. Is this possible or should I just scrap the old URL system and create an updated sitemap?

Answer (score 2):

From other users attemping this I believe it isn't possible without some kind of proxy service in front of your bucket.

here is a link from SO that explains about the keys being immutable, however, a default document seems to be supported but I haven't tested this yet.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236472/rewriting-amazon-s3-static-urls